# tooltipster extends height/width of window

Tags: css, tooltipster

I'm using tooltipster [library](https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/), it works fine on desktop. But on mobile when there is no enough space it extends width/height, so my fixed elements like footer/header moving when I open tooltip.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tooltipster').tooltipster();
});
<div style="text-align: right">
    <span class="tooltipster" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.">show me</span>
</div>
```

Full code here https://plnkr.co/edit/t4fa4Rj6GhReAaSYeXtq?p=preview

Temporary solution: remove arrow like this:

```
.tooltipster-arrow {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does your screenshot show? And if the tooltip overflows the window, it's expected that the body will be extended. What were you hoping for?

Comment: it show that fixed footer and header moves when tooltip shows. I expect that it shouldn't moves. For example twitter bootstrap tooltip works fine

Comment: You should open an issue on the github project. Make sure you use the latest version of the library.

Comment: Actually I can see that your plunker uses the old v3.3.0. Close this SO question if the latest version solves it.